# In D3 sankey.layout(32) what does 32 stands for?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The number 32 what does it stands for.

```
sankey
  .nodes(uniqueNodes)
  .links(links)
  .layout(32);
```

Comment: It was the [*iterations*](https://github.com/d3/d3-sankey#sankey_iterations) parameter.

Comment: 32 iterations and 1 iterations produce the same result. What does exactly the difference caused by 32 iterations. @Kaiido

Comment: Isn't 32 the default value?

Comment: if using (1) and (32) produce the same result, then that's a good thing and probably means your graph is relatively simple.  Each iteration will attempt to improve the layout, which means nodes are more aligned with those they are connected to, and less overlap of links.